# What devices suitable to provide wired LAN from Wi-Fi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, rj-45

I want to move my NAS where I don't have a wired connection. So I am looking for a device that connects to my Wi-Fi network and provides an RJ-45 port.

I found many devices such as "Access Point", "Repeater", "Range Extender", "Router", but these devices mostly do the opposite: provide Wi-Fi from LAN.

What kind of device am I looking for?

Comment: Although I've never bought any, I'm pretty sure I've seen this mode in a lot of "range extenders" that people use (as an option). It's fundamentally troublesome doing this with standard Wi-Fi though – don't be surprised if inbound connections to the NAS sometimes stop working – so I'm somewhat tempted to suggest a pair of _dedicated_ point-to-point Wi-Fi bridges (the kind people might use between two buildings) as those use a slightly different wireless protocol more suitable for bridging than standard Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a wireless bridge or a switch adapter,
which is a device which takes WiFi as input and converts it into
Ethernet connections.

An Amazon search for
[Wireless to ethernet](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Wireless+to+ethernet)
came up with several devices, where one contributed this schema:

[image]

Devices from reputed router makers may perform better than those
on Amazon.

Comment: Most devices I found are USB-WiFi, or the others are very slow (300Mbps)

Comment: For more serious devices, as I said, look in the websites of reputed router makers, now that you know how these devices are called.

Answer (score 0):

> What kind of device am I looking for?

A wireless access point in ***client*** (or station) mode, which is one half of a wireless bridge.  Normally a wireless-router or WAP operates in a "server" mode, and broadcasts its SSID.  But in client/station mode, the WAP is scanning for the SSID (from the wireless "server").

One solution is to use a suitable wireless router reprogrammed with [DD-WRT](https://www.wi-fiplanet.com/dd-wrt-tutorial-3-building-a-wireless-bridge/)

[image]

For ease of use, assign a static IP address to the "secondary router" (the WAP client) so that you always know how to access it (and its configuration page).

There are alternative schemes for linking wireless routers, e.g. mesh networking.  See https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Linking_Routers for other possibilities.
A reprogrammed wireless router is likely to be more cost effective than a dedicated AP client device, but may require more effort/labor to setup/configure.